# failed to upload file from minio api after using haproxy

Tags: haproxy, minio

I have two `haproxy` servers, the configuration of `serverA` is：

```
backend serverb
    mode http
    option redispatch
    option abortonclose
    server serverb 10.75.8.26:1443 weight 1 check rise 2 fall 3
the configuration of serverB is：
backend web
    balance roundrobin
    mode http
    server web 10.35.211.81:443 check ssl verify none
```

Now I can access the `webpage` on web server, but an error occurred when uploading the file with minioapi：

`Request Method: POST；Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error`.

Is there some other configuration about file update?

I try to change `ServerB` to `"mode: TCP"`, but also the same error.